# Java program file output upload to Squarespace site

Tags: java, file, upload, squarespace

In summary I have a java program that writes a file and I would like to now take that file and upload it to my Squarespace website. From here I am trying to figure out what my next steps are.

Comment: And what exactly is keeping you from doing just that?

Comment: Find out the Squarespace API's that you can use to upload. Write a program in Java to read your file and do a upload operation using REST API's of squarespace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve your questions, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). From this question you can not expect that much help. You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you then have a specific problem SO can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Squarespace currently only offers [APIs](https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-apis/overview) related to commerce (inventory, orders, products, transactions) and forms. There is no file storage-related API.

The only ways to upload files are via the WYSIWYG editor (via the add-link button), via the CSS Editor (for image assets) and via developer mode.

Squarespace 7.0 sites (current sites are 7.1 by default) that have Developer Mode enabled do support Git and SFTP. Theoretically, one could develop a system that utilized one of those methods in order to add files to the site (which would then be accessible via /assets), but that is only theoretical and far from ideal.

I'm afraid there isn't a good method for automatically uploading files to a Squarespace site.

Comment: that is very good information, thank you.